# Member initialization

Tags: c++

I'm associating a fix sized array of objects of a class Ghost with another class board. The ghost class has the default constructor as follows:

```
Ghosts(int x = 0, int y=0)
{
    x_pos = x;
    y_pos = y;
}
```

A part of my Board class is as follows:

```
class Board {
private:    

    Ghosts G[4];

public:

    Board(): G[0](11,18),G[1](13,21),G[2](15,18),G[3](13,18)
    {
        G[0].name("Pinky");
        G[1].name("Blinky");
        G[2].name("Inky");
        G[3].name("Clyde");
    }
```

The problem's with my member initialization list or maybe my approach towards it. Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The member initializer list can only name members. `G` is a member. `G[0]` is not.

You could change it to `: G{ {11,18}, {13,21}, {15,18}, {13,18} }`

Comment: Although the errors are no more there, but my positions are initialized to 0, not {11,18}, {13,21}, {15,18}, {13,18}.

Comment: @chillax in your example you wrote `G[0](11,18)`, I assumed this means you wanted `11` and `18` as the initializers. Write `: G{}` if you want all zeroes

Comment: Yes, you've assumed correctly! But its not working. I do want the ghosts to be initialized at those positions respectively. However, its not giving the correct output. All the ghosts are being initialized to 0.

Comment: @chillax maybe you have a bug elsewhere in your code.  It would help to post the class definition of `Ghosts` , and preferably, a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
Ghosts(int x = 0, int y=0, std::string name = "")
{
    x_pos = x;
    y_pos = y;
    this->name = name;
}

Board()
{
    G[0] = Ghost(11,18, "Pinky");
    G[1] = Ghost(13,21, "Blinky");
    G[2] = Ghost(15,18, "Inky");
    G[3] = Ghost(13,18, "Clyde");
}
```

Comment: What if `Ghosts` does not have copy/move assignment?

Comment: @Zereges Do they really need that?

Comment: Yes, because you're assigning them inside `Board`'s constructor.